# async await function does not change the variable after the second request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm having problems with the **ASYNC AWAIT** functions.
here's what I'm doing:
I have this async function which uses await, for example, getuserdata

```
// I am trying to check multiple users as much as possible basically.
getuserdata("Swift")
getuserdata("someotherperson")

async function getuserdata(username){
  //inside this I have 2 await functions which await a value from 2 different async functions. for example: user balance and user id
var userbalance = await getuserbalance(username)
var userid = await getuserid(username)
console.log(username + " has " + userbalance + " as balance and their user ID is: " userid)
//Now let's say we want to check 2 users a few times a minute to keep their balance up to date, so we run the function again
getuserdata(username)
}

//but in both of the functions (getuserbalance and getuserid) I have a web request which also uses await
// here's an example
async function getuserbalance(username){
    var request = await axios({
        url: "https://example.com/api/userbalance.php?username="+username,
        method: "GET"
    })
    return request.data
}

async function getuserid(username){
    var request = await axios({
        url: "https://example.com/api/userid.php?username="+username",
        method: "GET"
    })
    return request.data
}
```

Now this is where the error comes in
the first 2 times this works fine for me.
So the first 2 times it would show this in the console:

> > > Swift has 100 as balance and their user ID is: 1
> > >       someotherperson has 4 as balance and their user ID is: 2

But after 2 runs it just keeps on showing this:

> > > someotherperson has 4 as balance and their user ID is: 2

But then after like 15 requests, it switches to the first one again.
so it'll keep saying

> > > Swift has 100 as balance and their user ID is: 1

For around 15 requests and then it switches again.
any way to make it so it actually updates the value every time?

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

This might satisfy your requirement. Please replace db with your API calls

```js
db = {'p1': {'balance': 300, 'id': 1}, 'p2': {'balance': 540, 'id': 2}, 'p3': {'balance': 800, 'id': 3}}
users = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'];
tries_per_each_employee = 2;

(async () => {
   // Parallel way of testing for multiple Employees
   await Promise.all(users.map(p => getuserdata(p, tries_per_each_employee))).then(() => console.log('Done Checking all Users in Parallel.'));
   
   // Synchronous Way
   for(let u of users) {
      await getuserdata(u, tries_per_each_employee);
   }
   console.log('Done Checking all Users in Series.');
})();

async function getuserdata(username, tries){
    const userbalance = await getuserbalance(username)
    const userid = await getuserid(username)
    console.log(username + " has " + userbalance + " as balance and their user ID is: " + userid)

    tries <= 1 ? Promise.resolve() : await getuserdata(username, tries - 1);
}

async function getuserbalance(username){
    return db[username].balance;
}

async function getuserid(username){
    return db[username].id;
}
```

Comment: And I want to use the variables userbalance and userid further on aswell so yea

Comment: Is the code I drafted is not working or its not working as per your requirement? The getuserdata method you have written has an Infinite Loop. I made it to have a fixed number of tries.

Comment: It's not working per my requirement,
I have an array where I can add multiple items,
then it loops trough those items and runs a check like I explained up there and then I need it to run again
so basically it runs itself again after the function is done.

Comment: Can you please check the edited answer and confirm it.